# Can you bind the default network interface of the host into the container to read network stats?

Tags: node.js, linux, docker

I have a project where I read system information from the host inside a container. Right now I got CPU, RAM and Storage to work, but Network turns out to be a little harder. I am using the Node.js library https://systeminformation.io/network.html, which reads the network stats from `/sys/class/net/`.

The only solution that I found right now, is to use `--network host`, but that does not seem like the best way, because it breaks a lot of other networking related stuff and I cannot make the assumption that everybody who uses my project is fine with that.

I have tried `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway` as well, but while it does show up in `/etc/hosts`, it does not add a network interface to `/sys/class/net/`.

My knowledge on Docker and Linux is very limited, so does someone know if there is any other way?

> My workaround for now is, to use `readlink -f /sys/class/net/$(ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF; exit}')` to get the final path to the network statistics of the default interface and mount it to a imaginary path in the container. Therefore I don't use the mentioned `systeminformation` library for that right now. I would still like to have something that is a bit more reliable and in the best case officially supported by docker. I am fine with something that is not compatible with `systeminformation`, though.

Comment: `--network host` does what you're asking.  But if you're trying to probe a bunch of system-level information, from the host system, do Docker's isolation features actually meet your needs?  You might find it easier to run this project outside a container.

Comment: @DavidMaze the main reason that this project is dockerized, is that one of its key features is ease of install. It's a selfhosted consumer application. `--network host` does *technically* do what I am asking, but it also does a bunch of other things that I would like to avoid.

Comment: Just to elaborate: The things that I would like to avoid are, that the default docker networking and encapsulation does not work anymore with `--network host`, so I have to take a guess on the end-users infrastructure, which I can not make in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to enter the host network namespace after starting the container. This can be used to run one process in the container in the container network namespace and another process in the host network namespace. Communication between the processes can be done using a unix domain socket.

Alternatively you can just mount a new instance of the sysfs which points to the host network namespace. If I understood correctly this is what you really need.

For this to work you need access to the host `net` namespace (I mount /proc/1/ns/net to the container for this purpose). Additionally the capabilities CAP_SYS_PTRACE and CAP_SYS_ADMIN are needed.

```bash
# /proc/1 is the 'init' process of the host which is always running in host network namespace
$ docker run -it --rm --cap-add CAP_SYS_PTRACE --cap-add CAP_SYS_ADMIN -v /proc/1/ns/net:/host_ns_net:ro debian:bullseye-slim bash
root@8b40f2f48808:/ ls -l /sys/class/net
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  2 21:09 eth0 -> ../../devices/virtual/net/eth0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  2 21:09 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo

# enter the host network namespace
root@8b40f2f48808:/ nsenter --net=/host_ns_net bash

# now we are in the host network namespace and can see the host network interfaces
root@8b40f2f48808:/ mkdir /sys2
root@8b40f2f48808:/ mount -t sysfs nodevice /sys2
root@8b40f2f48808:/ ls -l /sys2/class/net/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 25  2021 enp2s0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 25  2021 enp3s0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
[...]

root@8b40f2f48808:/ ls -l /sys2/class/net/enp2s0/
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Oct 25  2021 addr_assign_type
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Oct 25  2021 addr_len
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Oct 25  2021 address
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Oct 25  2021 broadcast
[...]

# Now you can switch back to the original network namespace
# of the container; the dir "/sys2" is still accessible
root@8b40f2f48808:/ exit
```

**Putting this together for non-interactive usage:**

Use the `docker run` with the following parameters:

`docker run -it --rm --cap-add CAP_SYS_PTRACE --cap-add CAP_SYS_ADMIN -v /proc/1/ns/net:/host_ns_net:ro debian:bullseye-slim bash`

Execute these commands in the container before starting your node app:

```bash
mkdir /sys2
nsenter --net=/host_ns_net mount -t sysfs nodevice /sys2
```

After nsenter (and mount) exits, you are back in the network namespace of the container. In theory you could drop the extended capabilities now.

Now you can access the network devices under /sys2/class/net.

Comment: That seems very promising - thank you! You deserve the bounty. Just one question - wouldn't the final script also need the `exit` command? Or better said, what happens, if I don't exit before? Will my application ports then run on the host network?

Comment: Oh and one more question - how do I find out the default interface from `/sys2` if that is possible?

Comment: the `exit` is implicit because nsenter executes the mount command in the host network namespace and afterwards (when mount exits) you are back in the network namespace of the container.

Comment: During running "nsenter --net=/host_ns_net ..."  you can use `ip route show default` when you have `ip` installed.
Important is that the call is made within the context of the nsenter, e.g. put the mount and the `ip route show default` commands together in one script and call nsenter with the script as parameter instead of calling 'mount' directly.

Comment: Instead of using `ip route show default` you can also access the information in /proc/net/route. You have to search for the line which has `Destination==00000000 && Mask==00000000`.
Actually there is no concept of a default interface. There is the concept of a default route and the (default) gateway is reached via a specific interface. That's the reason why you probably will not find that info in /sys2/class/net.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I have now implemented it and it seems to fully work :)
To make it re-runnable without failing, I have changed the commands executed to the following:

`mkdir -p /mnt/host_sys`, then `mountpoint -q /mnt/host_sys || nsenter --net=/mnt/host_ns_net mount -t sysfs nodevice /mnt/host_sys` and in the end (to get the default network interface name) `nsenter --net=/mnt/host_ns_net route | grep default | awk '{print $8}'`.

Comment: I am running `nsenter --net=/mnt/host_ns_net` twice, because I am spawning a sub process in node for each of the commands, so it should be no problem, if I got that right.

Answer (score 0):

You could mount the host's `/sys/class/net/` directory as a volume in your container and patch the `systeminformation` package to read the contents of your custom path instead of the default path. The changes would need to be made in [`lib/network.js`](https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation/blob/master/lib/network.js). You can see in that file how the directory is hardcoded throughout, just do a find/replace in your local copy to change all instances of the default path.

Comment: `/sys/class/net/` only contains hardlinks to the real paths, so I would first have to manually find out what the real path is on the host. That's what I am doing right now (check the note in my question), but it is non-trivial for the user.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to mount the whole "/sys" filesystem of the host into the container. Either mount them to a new location (e.g. /sys_host) or over-mount the original "/sys" in the container:

```
# docker run -it --rm -v /sys:/sys:ro debian:bullseye-slim bash
root@b84df3184dce:/# ls -l /sys/class/net/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 25  2021 enp2s0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:02:00.0/net/enp2s0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 25  2021 enp3s0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
[...]

root@b84df3184dce:/# ls -l /sys/class/net/enp2s0/
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Oct 25  2021 addr_assign_type
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Oct 25  2021 addr_len
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Oct 25  2021 address
-r--r--r--  1 root root 4096 Oct 25  2021 broadcast
[...]
```

Please be aware that this way the container has access to the whole "/sys" filesystem of the host. The relative links from the network interface to the pci device still work.

If you don't need to write you should mount it read-only by appending ":ro" to the mounted path.